# how to handle 'HTTP session already opened' error in ruby?

Tags: ruby, facebook

I am trying to fetch user details on facebook via user's access_token. HTTPS   needs to be enabled.

```
get '/fbdetails' do
 uri = URI('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAMF7kse5oFQyygDDgOZCMQFvddZBEskIdxiNlmWd2Mzx3lLWZCoZCJZCjXnMN08NLe8Ts8UJoOd9XjNrJ9QG5BsZC9ahB0h9NcdSDZA0LDdjfmtiXnmimyNZBTTxv7UT1ZBcz2vbKj2DYZAAGdoy7woJEcu1ZAoFpzcpaa47mz0DLwgNPY6PZA0Vrc7ZAT9snEZC6XdiUZAkgUZARvhBIxlltqEEelAZD')
 Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
 :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https').start do |http|
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
    response = http.request 
  end
  return response 
end
```

Here, an IOError is thown i.e HTTP session already opened.

Need JSON response in this format:

```
{ 
  "id": "10206515808233150",
  "first_name": "Ashutosh",
  "gender": "male",
  "last_name": "Jha",
  "link": "https://www.facebook.com/app_scoped_user_id/10206515808233150/",
  "locale": "en_US",
  "name": "Ashutosh Jha",
  "timezone": 5.5,
  "updated_time": "2015-02-17T16:38:08+0000",
  "verified": true
}
```

Comment: how about using the gem koala - https://github.com/arsduo/koala

Comment: ya that is an easy way. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two errors for your codes.

(1) you used the `start` method twice, so that thown the "HTTP session already opened" error.

```
Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
 :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https').start do |http|....
```

(2) you miss the parameter for `http.request`

```
response = http.request
```

so your codes should be:

```
 uri = URI('https://graph.facebook.com/me?access_token=CAACEdEose0cBAMF7kse5oFQyygDDgOZCMQFvddZBEskIdxiNlmWd2Mzx3lLWZCoZCJZCjXnMN08NLe8Ts8UJoOd9XjNrJ9QG5BsZC9ahB0h9NcdSDZA0LDdjfmtiXnmimyNZBTTxv7UT1ZBcz2vbKj2DYZAAGdoy7woJEcu1ZAoFpzcpaa47mz0DLwgNPY6PZA0Vrc7ZAT9snEZC6XdiUZAkgUZARvhBIxlltqEEelAZD')
 Net::HTTP.start(uri.host, uri.port,
 :use_ssl => uri.scheme == 'https') do |http|
    request = Net::HTTP::Get.new uri.request_uri
    response = http.request request
    #puts response.body
  end
```

You can find more useful info from [ruby net/http library doc](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.2.2/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html).